# How long can you marinade chicken, keeping it in the fridge?

Tags: chicken, frying

There is a famous fried [chicken recipe of Google chef Charlie Ayers](https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2004/05/chicken-la-king.html#:%7E:text=Pour%20the%20batter%20over%20the%20chickens%20and%20marinate%20for%20up%20to%20five%20days%20%2D%20keep%20refrigerated%2C%20of%20course.) . This recipe calls for marinating chicken in the fridge for 5 days. However [Nestle](https://www.nestle-family.com/en/article/chicken-%E2%80%93-handling-it-safe-way#:%7E:text=Marinated%20chicken%20can%20be%20kept,uncooked%20marinade%20should%20be%20discarded.), and [USDA](https://ask.usda.gov/s/article/How-long-can-meat-and-poultry-be-marinated) say that marinated chicken should not be kept in the fridge for more than 2 days. So which is right?

Comment: I think you have misread the recipe.  It says "marinate for **up to** five days".

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest going with the advice of the USDA over Nestle corporation. That said, the USDA site does not state that longer than 2 days is unsafe, rather that marinades, which tend to be acidic, begin to break down the protein after this point.  That is a texture and preference issue rather than a safety issue. The recipe you link contains buttermilk (also acidic).  I suspect that this will impact the texture of the final product IF it were held for 5 days.   However, the recipe does NOT say to marinate for 5 days, but that you can hold it for UP TO 5 days.

Marinades are a surface treatment.  You don't get added benefit beyond a few hours.  The marinade does contain quite a bit of salt, so there may be some brining happening.  Again, not much added benefit after a few hours or a day.

In the end, I would be personally more concerned with texture.  Over night is plenty...maybe two days....yes it will be safe at day 5, but you might not like the texture as much.